# PHP - sorting an array of filenames with numbers?

Tags: php, arrays, string, sorting, numbers

Can anyone tell me how to sort an array containing filenames that start with numbers? Because strings that start with 11, 12, 13 etc are considered lower than 2, it's scewing my results like this:

```
[0] "1. File one.pdf"
[1] "11. File eleven.pdf"
[2] "12. File twelve.pdf"
[3] "2. File two.pdf"
[4] "3. File three.pdf"
```

Is there anything I can do to sort these properly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [natsort](http://php.net/natsort). or [natcasesort](http://php.net/natcasesort), which is case insensitive. If there is more than numbers (ie. diacritics), you should assure that you use proper [locale](http://php.net/setlocale).

If it is not enough, ie. you want also sort number literals ("one", "two", "three"), you can use [usort](http://php.net/natsort), which permits to use your custom callback as comparison function.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, and everyone else who put in an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use can get the natural ordering using [natsort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php)

<strike>**See it.**</strike>

Comment: What was the link supposed to be? It's dead now.